# Fail to connect to camera service in Android

Tags: android, video, android-camera, surfaceview, record

I'd like to switch between back and front camera to record a video.
This is my code:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    if (usecamera) {
        camera = Camera.open(0);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewRunning = true;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG,e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }       

}


public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    if (!recording && usecamera) {
        if (previewRunning){
            camera.stopPreview();
        }

        try {
            Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

            p.setPreviewSize(camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth, camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight);

            camera.setParameters(p);

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewRunning = true;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG,e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        prepareRecorder();  
    }
}


public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (recording) {
        recorder.stop();
        recording = false;
    }
    recorder.release();
    if (usecamera) {
        previewRunning = false;
        //camera.lock();
        camera.release();
    }

}
```

In the first instance the preview of the back camera is correct, but crash when I try to change the camera:

The button for change is:

```
changeCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras()>=2) {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    //"which" is just an integer flag
                    switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                        which = 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
                        which = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                        camera.startPreview();
                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        camera.release();
                        camera = null;
                    }
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post the messages you see in logcat. Probably there is not only the exception stack of your app, but some error messages from camera service, too.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Android Camera API is not easy to understand. There are two **int** [constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_BACK):

```
public final static int Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK = 0;
public final static int Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT = 1;
```

and there are methods, like [Camera.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29) that expect `int cameraId` parameter.

But it is a mistake to use the constants above for [Camera.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29) or [CamcorderProfile.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#get%28int,%20int%29). The **cameraId** is **0** for first camera, **1** for the second, **2** for third, an so on, up to `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()-1`. You can check the *direction* of a camera with certain **cameraId** as follows:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
int facing = camera.getCameraInfo().facing();
```

The value of **facing** is guaranteed to be either [Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_BACK) or [Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_FRONT).